# How do you save and retrieve reports that are favorites using reportservice2010 web service?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am using SSRS web service to get report information but I am unable to figure out how to get favorite or set favorite for reports outside of reporting services without querying/inserting directly to the reporting service database (which I don't want to do).  Can someone help with this or has any experience with how to get and set this data through the web service?

```
ReportingService2010 reportingService2010 = new ReportingService2010();
reportingService2010.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
reportingService2010.Url = "http://myreportingserver";
```

Comment: While I have no answer using ReportingService2010. The modern way to do this is: http://blog.ctglobalservices.com/powershell/pbw/automating-ssrs-favorites-with-rest-api/